# Certificate error on this meta

Tags: bug

Getting certificate error for this meta in Chrome/Vivaldi:

> Your connection is not private
>
> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>
> This server could not prove that it is meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com; its security certificate is from *.stackexchange.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Clicked through from [bot entry in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34345292#34345292) and bot seems to have converted non-SSL `http://` link to protocol–relative `//`.

Comment: I knew something is wrong with this meta :))) Good catch. Duped.